# StandardForm on Graph edges

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The `Graph` command displays edge labels in `TraditionalForm`. I instead want to use `StandardForm`.

I tried

`EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[StandardForm, Background -> White]`, but of course it does not work.

So how to do it, acting on `EdgeLabelStyle`?

Edit: Comment to @Sjoerd examples
Your Binomial example is somewhat misleading, since Binomial has an intrinsic TraditionalForm version. What we are seeing in the graph is a sort of hybrid of Standardform (for n and k) and TraditionalForm for the parenthesis (I think). This is the proof:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you see, even though I used braces in the notation, I still get the parenthesis in the graph (from the internal TraditionalForm), but the n, k are indeed in StandardForm.

This shows that the "StandardForm" in EdgelabelStyle does something, but it is not enough. Perhaps it is possible to play with BaseStyle?

The same thing happens if you use MakeBoxes (without ToString).

Answer (score 6):

The style names should be between quotes (this is stated in the `Style` doc page, under the 'More Information' section)

```
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};
GraphicsRow[{
  Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> Exp[I x/10], 
         EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive["StandardForm", Red, 30], 
         ImagePadding -> 15],
   Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> Exp[I x/10], 
         EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive["TraditionalForm", Red, 30], 
         ImagePadding -> 15]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comments I tried to work with `Notation` and `MakeBoxes`.

`Notation` doesn't seem to cause problems:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`MakeBoxes` seem to work if you use `ToString`:

```
gplus /: MakeBoxes[gplus[x_, y_, n_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{MakeBoxes[x, StandardForm], 
   SubscriptBox["\[CirclePlus]", MakeBoxes[n, StandardForm]], 
   MakeBoxes[y, StandardForm]}]

edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};
GraphicsRow[{
  Graph[edges, 
    EdgeLabels -> ToString[gplus[a, b, c], StandardForm], 
    EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive["StandardForm", Red, 30], 
    ImagePadding -> 30],
  Graph[edges, 
    EdgeLabels -> ToString[gplus[a, b, c], StandardForm], 
    EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive["TraditionalForm", Red, 30], 
    ImagePadding -> 30]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is very good!....but now there is another problem. For some reason, StandardForm is indeed displayed, but my custom notation (created with Notation and MakeBoxes[....StandardForm]) are no longer working. I also tried "Output" and "Text", to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: @magma Tried something (see edits). If this doesn't work for you, you probably should be more specific in how you use `Notation` and `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: thank you @Sjoerd. Please read my edited question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StandardForm` to wrap the labels:

```
 edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};
 GraphicsRow[{Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> Exp[I x/10], 
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 30], ImagePadding -> 15], 
 Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> TraditionalForm[Exp[I x/10]], 
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 30], ImagePadding -> 15], 
 Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> StandardForm[Exp[I x/10]], 
 EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 30], ImagePadding -> 15]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that before asking here, but I really do not wish to mess up with the labels

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer using `String` for labels instead of evaluable expressions (in case they are messed up because of incautious assignments).

```
edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};

Graph[edges, EdgeLabels -> {
                  1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> Style[
                               ToString[HoldForm[
                                    Integrate[Exp[(I*x)/10], {x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]}]
                                   ], StandardForm],
                               FontFamily -> "Times", Blue, 15, Bold],
                  2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> "text",
                  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1 -> ToString[HoldForm[
                               Integrate[Exp[(I*x)/10], {x, \[Alpha], \[Beta]}]
                                            ], TraditionalForm]
                           },
             EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 30], ImagePadding -> 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is not good for me Silvia. In my case case the label are "the message", so I want them to evaluate and stay untouched

Comment: @magma In that case maybe you could remove the `HoldForm` wrapper, so the expression will be evaluated when generating the label content. Converting it to `String` is aimed at preventing the generated graph being modified by latter evaluation. eg. The graph is wrapped in a `Dynamic`, then a latter assignment, say `x = 0`, may cause `Exp[I x/10]` becoming `1`. But if this behavior is indeed what you need, then using `String` will be inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just use the [`FormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatType) option of [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph). First, your notation:

[image]

Then, the graph:

```
Graph[{1<->2, 2<->3, 3<->1}, EdgeLabels->Binomial[n,k], FormatType->StandardForm]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carl. This was a very old question of mine. I will check your answer tomorrow (if I can still find the problem :-))